# IPCONFIG not showing external IP address - Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, ip, service

various services such as IIS and FTP are using the external IP address without problems.

**Unfortunately some other apps are having difficulty validating such IP, 
in fact when using the `ipconfig` command the IP does not show up!**

---

What could this be? Anyway I can fix this?

Comment: More detail please.

Comment: Maybe its nated.. more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you server is behind a firewall (NATed) there is not an external ip address on the server.

If you server is connected directly to the internet, try wiht `ipconfig /all`.